# Are desktop notifications not working in more recent TOR versions?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I ran a comparative test, two different versions, out-of-the-box, used same site to test:

This is the website that I used to test: https://www.bennish.net/web-notifications.html .

- Tor `12.0.3`: **working**
- Tor `12.5.5`: ***not* working**; displays the message `Permission to display: denied` when I click `Authorize`.

See also attached screenshot.

**Did something change regarding this ?**
I could not find anything in the changelog...

[image]